# Can't import a module in Django project

Tags: django

This is my django project folder:

```
mysite
├── mypage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    └── util.py
```

This is the error message that I get when I run the server.

```
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('mypage/', include('mypage.urls'))
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/mysite/mypage/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/gigidagostino/Desktop/django_experment/mysite/mypage/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mysite.utils.util import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.utils'
```

This is the view.py in mypage app folder:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from mysite.utils.util import *


def index(request):
    print_hi()
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

So the question is: How do I import util.py in view.py?
It does work if I just move the utils inside mypage folder, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it without moving utils folder.

Comment: you need to put `utils` folder inside `mysite` directory

Comment: It is inside mysite directory

Comment: i mean `mysite/mysite` dir

Comment: once I moved `utils` folder inside `mysite`, it still doesn't work. I tried importing like: `from ..mysite.utils.util import *`: it gives me `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. Then I tried like: `from mysite.mysite.utils.util import *`, and it gives me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.mysite'`

Comment: you need to import like `from mysite.utils.util import *`

Comment: I just tried that and now it seems like it does work, but in my PyCharm I'm getting: `Cannot find reference 'utils' in '__init__.py'` for some reason. Any idea on how to fix that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports)

like

```
from .utils.util import *
from ..utils.util import *
from ...utils.util import *
```

depending on your project structure

Comment: if I try to import doing like: `from ..utils.util import *`,  it gives me error:
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package